Can I cause a star to go supernova by altering the four fundamental forces?
I have the Scientocratic Hivemind. It has the ability to create and envelop things in a magic field. Within this field, it can choose to strengthen or weaken the four fundamental forces governing the atoms. This process happens by it altering the forces on every individual atoms that make up the target simultaneously and through accumulation of enough affected atoms cause a change on a macroscopic scale.
Now, I've thought of the Scientocratic Hivemind weaponizing this in the coolest manner possible and I've decided that supernovas are it. It envelops a big enough star within its field and detonate it by changing the four fundamental forces. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything after researching.
Is this possible? If so, what would it need to alter to achieve a supernova?

If you can manipulate the fundamental forces in such a manner over such a huge volume of space, causing a supernova honestly sounds like a weirdly mundane way to make use of that capability. You could shut down fission or fusion reactors across a wide swath of the system, you could slowly ramp up radioactive decay across the enemy planets/ships/stations until the target surrenders or succumbs to radiation sickness, you could make their homeworld uninhabitable for a century or so while unstable atoms decay without destroying it, etc.

@Vilarinof I like the way you put it. My (limited) understanding is, a supernova arises from an instability: fusion reactions near the center of the star lose efficiency as lighter nuclei (hydrogen and helium) are depleted while heavier ones (lithium etc.) accumulate; beyond a certain threshold, the energy output can no longer counteract the weight of the upper layers of the star, which imploses. The strength of the strong interaction determines the energy output of fusion reactions.

If you can play with laws, the answer is an obvious yes, but take care and not get caught by the alteration force, or else you'll likely cease to exist as well.

@ChristopherJamesHuff I gotta disagree, all of those sound wildly more boring and mundane than a supernova. Per Xkcd,  A supernova viewed from 93 million miles away is brighter than a hydrogen bomb detonated against your eyeball. “Shut down reactors across the system” is comically dull in comparison.

@DanielB A supernova's just a big explosion. They're not even that unusual of a natural event. It's not even going to apply the energy it releases very effectively to the target. You can unravel the structure of matter, why are you messing with supernovas?

@ChristopherJamesHuff I hope I never become so jaded as to stop thinking big explosions are very cool.

Once you introduced magic, you can just ignore any physics. So I am not sure why you are obsessed with the four fundamental forces.

@Vilarinof exactly. The worst a supernova could do is vaporize the planet. You could potentially convert much of it to energy by unbinding the protons and neutrons it's made of. Or you could turn it into glowing death for a thousand years. Or disable all high technology by altering the behavior of electronics. Or maybe just cause everyone to drop dead by tweaking chemical reactions. Astronomers see supernovae all the time, but you could reproduce conditions only seen during the Big Bang, or do terrifying things that nothing in nature does.

Just turn electromagnetic force off. Gravity and strong interaction will do the rest. If you can do it in a moment in the whole star volume, probably you will even get a small black hole in the center - a black hole whose mass is too small to be created in ordinary supernova explosions.

Yes, you can make a star go supernova by playing with the four fundamental forces.
If you increase gravity, the stellar mass will be squeezed together more strongly, thus increasing the rate of fusion and the temperature of the star.  Be careful, though, or your star might collapse into a black hole.
If you decrease electromagnetic forces, the energy required to fuse nuclei will decrease due to reduced repulsion between positively-charged nuclei, thus increasing the rate of fusion.
If you adjust the weak interaction so that protons decay to neutrons more rapidly, this will accelerate hydrogen-hydrogen fusion within a star, the proton-proton chain being one of the  limiters in the rate of fusion within a star.
If you increase the strong interaction, you can increase the capture radius for fusion reactions, thus increasing the rate of fusion.
Do several or all of these things, and you could make a star go supernova - or a reasonable facsimile of a supernova - relatively quickly... or you might just get a black hole.
Experimentation is recommended, but not upon your home planet's stellar primary.

While we don't actually know what's inside a black hole, assuming that it's just a bunch of mass-energy that's compacted sufficiently such that it's all within it's own Schwarzschild radius, then collapsing into a black hole could be a feature, making the explosion even larger, assuming you can then decrease gravity dramatically, resulting in it all explodes starting from the even smaller size (and the presumed conversion to energy of an even larger fraction of the mass, some of which would, probably, be converted while it's a black hole, but be unable to escape until gravity is reduced).

@Makyen detonating black holes by reducing gravity could be an option even eclipsing supernovae in strength - if you can release all the mass/energy contained in a supermassive black hole, the effect could be astronomic.

What's the cycle time on what they're doing?  Because of it's fast enough you can make a mighty big boom by turning the gravity way up for a very short period of time.  Everything rushes inward in response to the gravity, but when you turn it back off you now have a mass that's way too hot and dense and it promptly expands.  Proton-proton fusion is also temperature sensitive and will run wild when you squashed things.
This is similar to Monty Wild's answer but by doing it for a short enough time you can use far more pressure without simply causing a core collapse directly to a black hole.
You aren't limited to stars, either--anything with plenty of self-gravity but below a neutron star can be detonated.  The rebound can be extremely powerful even without any fusion.  (And, yes, it's an energy-from-nothing system.)

The electromagnetic force, is essentially what keeps atoms apart. Lower, or remove that in a part of the core of a star, for a moment, and all matter in that area would be pulled into a single point (sort of).
The power of the resulting explosion, can be controlled by where in the sun you do it, how large of an area, and how long you allow matter to merge.
You can now do anything from a full supernova, to a more localized solar flare that will "only" sterilize a section of the solar system (like a planet full of monkeys, or an incoming enemy fleet)

And if we can turn off the gravity things get even bigger.  A large neutron star can have half it's mass be in the form of binding energy.  I think that if you turn off the gravity that mass will appear as energy.  In the ballpark of 1000x your paltry supernova.
And a black hole can be considered to have all it's mass as binding energy.  We have something of a paradox here as the event horizon is in the way--but since black hole evaporation can shrink the event horizon I would think that if you turn off the gravity the event horizon disappears.  Detonate the supermassive black hole in the center of a galaxy and your supernova looks like a wet firecracker.

The main difference between a star and a fusion bomb is that the star gravity is so strong that it keeps the explosion caused by the ongoing fusion confined in its core, while metal casing used by the arm have shown the tendency to blow up.
Just weaken up the gravity within the star and let the explosion happen once there is no more weight to contain the core.

That won’t be a supernova, it will be the star’s normal energy output spreading over a wider area, and then declining. You want to strengthen gravity to bring on a core collapse.

You have it totally backwards.  The difference between a star and an h-bomb is the star is proton-proton fusion, the bomb is deuterium-tritium.  The latter reaction goes far, far faster.

Also, if stars worked the way you say every star would detonate on it's own.  Stars maintain an equilibrium where contraction causes heat which generates pressure which causes expansion.  Negative feedback loop.  If expansion caused fusion to go faster you would have a positive feedback loop.  And positive feedback loops very quickly max out the system (think microphone too close to the speaker) or detonate (if there's nothing which will max out short of system depletion--think high explosive.)

@LorenPechtel Indeed fusion in a star is so slow that the chemical process in your body generate more energy per cubic metre than the nuclear fusion in a star does.
